# Data not written to Firebase on button press

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Ok, so I'm hoping someone can help me with this problem since I've been trying a bunch of different solutions the past several days. Within my activity, I have an EditText and a Button and I'm trying to write that user input to Firebase. I don't get any errors when I run the application, however, when I press the button, nothing happens.

Here's my class:

```
private EditText userEmail;
Button sendInviteButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_registration);

    userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_email);
    sendInviteButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendInviteButton);

}

public void btn(View view) {
    sendInviteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://app-1318.firebaseio.com/clients");
            String enteredUserEmail = userEmail.getText().toString();
            ref.child("userBackgroundCheck").setValue(enteredUserEmail);
        }
    });
}
```

I do have an onClick for the button in XML so I truly have no idea why this data isn't being sent to Firebase.

Lastly, are we supposed to use the root URL for Firebase for this portion?:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://app-1318.firebaseio.com/clients");
```

Which would be:

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://app-1318.firebaseio.com");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go on your Firebase console and edit your database Rule . 
Below is the pic sample.

[image: Change your rules to that and see]

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try that now.

Comment: Changing the rules like this makes you database readable and writeable to everyone in the world. While this is a common practice when you just start developing, it is recommended that you change your code to use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) soon after. Once your users are authenticated (even if just [anonymously](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)), you can start [securing their access to your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).

Answer (score 2):

Did you tried adding rules under RealTime Database. When you go to Realtime Database click on Rules tab. Add below lines

```
// These rules give anyone, even people who are not users of your app,
// read and write access to your database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

See if it works!

Also why are you storing data in old way. Here is the [new doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/save-data) for saving data in realtime database.

Comment: I just got it to work right before I saw your solution. I'm definitely going to checkout the link you provide. Thanks!